# WPF Label Flowdirection text does not reverse with special characters

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to display the text "1/min" in a label with reversed FlowDirection, i.e. RightToLeft. However, the text remains the same with either "1/min" or "min/1".

Test code:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label FlowDirection="RightToLeft">1/min</Label>
        <Label FlowDirection="RightToLeft">min/1</Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Both labels show the same text, namely "min/1". I'm fairly certain that non-ascii chars cause this, but how do I get around that behaviour?

Comment: All it does for me is setting the text to be right aligned. Also if you use it with A `TextBox` it reverses the keyboard arrows, i.e. to move caret to the left I need to press right. I don't think this `FlowDirection` does what you want to achieve.

Comment: I would go with another approach. I checked here and `FlowDirection` is not like a Reverse function, it has many rules, that why has this 'strange' behaviour, and is intended to be used with other languages (RTL) like this http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/guy/2009/06/24/xaml-special-characters-and-white-spaces/

Comment: Maybe I should clarify that I don't want to use the FlowDirection to reverse the text. I want to use a reversed-flow label for a different purpose, but still my problem is that my intended text "1/min" does not show up on the reversed label.